# Calculating $P(X_n\ge 0)$, for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4$ in a random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

Let us take a random walk as follows, $$X_0 = 0;\ X_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} e_i$$

where,
$$
e_n=
\begin{cases} 
+1 \text{ with probability } p; \\
-1 \text{ with probability } q;
\end{cases}
$$
and all $e_n$ are independent variables, so I have to calculate

$$ \mathbb{P}(X_n\ge0,\forall\ n = 1,2,3,4 )$$

I know the standard results regarding random walks but I am drawing blanks here.

Comment: Also, since you only need the answer for small $n$, you could start with $n = 1$ and just write down all the possibilities. (and then $n = 2$ and so on...) Maybe that's enlightening as to what the pattern is

Comment: Note that OP is asking for $P(X_1 \ge 0, X_2 \ge 0, X_3 \ge 0, X_4 \ge 0)$, not $P(X_1 \ge 0), P(X_2 \ge 0), \ldots$.

Comment: @Clarinetist Technically $e_n$ is not a Bernoulli RV (although it is a linear transformation of one).

Comment: There are six possible paths so you can find the probability of each (you can also spot that the 4th step is irrelevant, so effectively only three possibilities)

Comment: Note that if $X_1 \geq 0,$ the first step was up, and the second step can go down or up; if it goes up, the next two steps are irrelevant; if it goes down, you restart the random walk from scratch but this time you are interested on only the steps 1 and 2 to be above zero.

Comment: Hint: consider the reflection principle -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)

Comment: $\dfrac{e_n + 1}{2}$ is Bernoulli and the sum of Bernoulli is binomial.

Comment: thank you guys for your comments, the problem is now clearer to me, and I should be able to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following binary tree shows all possible ways that we can have the event $X_n \geq 0,\;\forall{n}\in\{1,2,3,4\}$

[image]

Number of ways favorable to the event = number of possible paths from the root node to a leaf node in the tree = number of leaf nodes in the tree = 6, with the total probability $P(X_n \geq 0)$ summing up to $p^4 + p^3q + p^2qp + p^2q^2 + pqp^2 + pqpq=p^2(p^2+3pq+2q^2)$

Comment: Why can't the -1 at $e_2$ node, ie 2nd level not have a -1, since it only has a +1?

Comment: At level 2 of the tree (root node being at level 1), the nodes at this level represent all possible values of $e_2$, we have both $-1$ and $+1$. Here $e_i$ is associated with all nodes at level $i$, not with a single node.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}, \dfrac{e_i + 1}{2}$ is a Benoulli distribution of parameter $p$ then :
$$Y = \sum_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{e_i + 1}{2} = \dfrac{X_n + n}{2}$$
is a binomial distribution of parameter $(n, p)$.
we deduce that :
$$p(X_n \geq 0) = p (Y \geq \frac{n}{2}) = \sum_{k \geq \frac{n}{2}}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k q^{n - k}$$

- For $n = 1$ :
  $$p(X_1 \geq 0) = \binom{1}{1} p q^{1 - 1} = p$$
- For $n = 2$ :
  $$p(X_2 \geq 0) = \sum_{k = 1}^2 \binom{2}{k} p^k q^{2 - k} = 2 p q + p^2$$
- For $n = 3$ :
  $$p(X_3 \geq 0) = \sum_{k = 2}^3 \binom{3}{k} p^k q^{3 - k} = 3 p^2 q + p^3$$
- For $n = 4$ :
  $$p(X_4 \geq 0) = \sum_{k = 2}^4 \binom{4}{k} p^k q^{4 - k} = 6 p^2 q^2 + 4 p^3 q + p^4$$

Comment: The question is asking for $P(X_1 \ge 0, X_2 \ge 0, X_3 \ge 0, X_4 \ge 0)$, rather than $P(X_1 \ge 0)$, $P(X_2 \ge 0)$ and so on.